# Get programmatically Python3 default path in Octave base directory

Tags: octave, gnu

I am using GNU Octave. I have script written in python3 and it is working if I do something like that: (it's .m file)

```
setenv PYTHON python;

[output,status]=python('python_file.py');

output
```

But some users do not have installed Python on their own. I found that python3.exe is available in "C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.2.0\usr\bin" for default users.
It is possible to get Octave default path and then setenv python pointing to GNU Octave Python directory programically, everything wrote in octave_file.m?

Python file:

```
import sys
import subprocess
python = sys.executable
subprocess.check_call([python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

...
```

result from octave:

```
/usr/bin/python.exe: No module named pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\cw1.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call([python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what you're trying to do...

Comment: If someone run this program in Octave GNU, I want to set his Python environment to his python3.exe located in defautl folder GNU Octave\Octave-6.2.0\usr\bin, a then I want to install Numpy if is not installed yet.